# How can I use the designer for an inherited user control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I try to use the designer for an inherited user control, unfortunately without success.

[image: My setting]

My problem is, that I can't design the `ConcreteWizardTemplate` as I expect. It works flawless when `AbstractWizardElement` is derived from a `Form`, but even not with `UserControl`. If I open my `ConcreteWizardTemplate` with the designer, I could add components from the tool box, though I can't design nor style them.

```
#if DEBUG
    public class AbstractWizardElement : UserControl
    {
         ..
    }
#else
    public abstract class AbstractWizardElement : UserControl
    {
         ..
    }
#endif
```

There is a compiler switch, that define the `AbstractWizardElement` as a normal class, when the debug mode is on.

[image: My problem]

How can I design my `ConcreteWizardTemplate` like I do with a element which inherits from a `Form`?

My environment is Visual Studio 2010 with C#.net 4.0.

Comment: There's an interesting quirk with Visual Studio in that it doesn't run the constructor of the derived class/control in the designer. I've often fixed this issue by creating another control that inherits from the original control (in this case, say ConcreteWizardTemplateShim : ConcreteWizardTemplate) and have then designed that in the designer. Does that work for you?

Comment: Is your base class marked as abstract? Because if that is the case, the designer cannot create an instance of that control.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @dash. I have another control, which inherits the `ConcreteWizardTemplate`. Unfortunately, I can't 'style' them too!

Comment: @Spontifixus: Yes, it is, when I don't run the solution in the debug mode. There is a compiler switch to define it as a normal class, when it's in the debug mode.

Comment: Maybe you know all this, but nonetheless I have to ask: Do the `ConcreteWizardTemplate` and its base classes all have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yes, there is a parameterless constructor.